# defining date in json file

Tags: javascript, json, date

I wonder to know how to set today's date in json file like we are using in js.

Is there any option to specify Date.today() in json file?

Because, json data has date object which specifies system date whenever we read the json file.

Hope, you will understand what i am trying to say.

Thanks in advance,

-Raja.

Comment: Where does the json file come from and what are you going to do with its contents? Does it just contain values you're going to use within your javascript code, or are you going to generate output (such as HTML) from the data as well?

Comment: I need to get the date and have to perform some calculations in html side

Comment: i do not really get your problem. I did read the comments you made, but could you please specify a little bit more whats your problem is? Perhaps an example, why you need that. - thanks

Comment: Trying very hard to make sense of the question but it really lacks an example input and expected behaviour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

JSON is a structured transport format. It does not have logic in it.

But here are options:

1. Why not just get the date when you read the file instead?
2. Have a server generate that JSON that includes the date at which it was generated. However, this is not ideal if you want the current date. By the time you read the file, the date generated by the server is already past.
3. build a parser that parses a string and make it search for custom markup.

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/99NJV/), special markup is contained in `@{}`. Get the command inside, determine the command, and execute replacement.

```
var jsonString = '{"data1" : "foo","date" : "@{currentdate}"}'
```

In this case, I'll find `@{currentdate}`. I should create a function corresponding to this command to replace `@{currentdate}` into the current date during read (in the format you want)

```
var parsedString = jsonString.replace(/@\{(\w+)\}/g, function(match, group) {    
    if (group === 'currentdate') {
        return new Date();
    } 
    else if (group === 'anotherCommand') {
        return 'anotherValue';
    } //and so on
});
```

and the result is like this:

```
jsonString = '{"data1" : "foo","date" : "Fri May 04 2012 01:17:07 GMT-0700 (PDT)"}'
```

Comment: Not only one date. i have lot of date objects in json data. Getting the date while reading is not a good one. I need to be done it in json itself. Is there any other way?

Comment: @RajaGopal have a server generate the json file, so that it can append the current generated date. AFAIK, JSON does not contain logic. it's just a transport format.

Comment: @RajaGopal then have a recursive function do it.

Comment: Thanks, But, we will get a json object when we read from json file. How to we will replace the @{xxx} value into original value? Is it possible to get as json string and replace?

Comment: @RajaGopal I suppose you could also do a replace directly to the JSON string. But if you get it as an object, you have to do recursion to find those special markup and replace them with the current date upon reading.

Comment: Thanks, How to get a json data (which is avail from json file) as string in js?

Comment: @RajaGopal you can load it via [AJAX](http://www.degraeve.com/reference/simple-ajax-example.php) which returns to you a string of the file contents.

Comment: I am using Date.today() to get today's date. So i have given it as string in json file

Comment: using eval i converted into valid date in js file. But, how could i replace the string into date value?

Comment: @RajaGopal if you are getting the JSON as a string, do a replace operation for all the special markup (like in my answer, the `@{}`) and replace them with the date (like `2012-12-21`) and not a Date object. once you parse the JSON using `JSON.parse()`, the dates are current. these are all done when you read the JSON string. in your file, there are no function calls or whatever, just the special markup to represent an operation done during read.

Answer (score 14):

Server side can generate JSON dates in ISO format for example "2012-04-30T02:15:12.356Z"
Then client side can parse and load into date object

```
new Date(Date.parse("2012-04-30T02:15:12.356Z"))
```

Answer (score 5):

I suggest that you consider using the [JSON-js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) ([json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js)) parser, because it parses all standard JSON, but also allows you to add custom parse handling logic, called a `reviver` function, which fits your scenario very well. The basic syntax to invoke the JSON parser with a custom handler looks like this:

`var myObject = JSON.parse(myJSONtext, reviverFunction);`

Using your example input as a guide, it could be set up to work like this:

```
var jsonTxt = '[{' +
        '"data1": "foo",' +
        '"Date":  "",' +
        '"childs": [{' +
            '"data2": "stack",' +
            '"Date": ""' +
        '}{}{}...]}]';    //and-on-and-on as in your comment

myData = JSON.parse(jsonTxt, function ( key, value ) {
    if ( key === 'Date') { return new Date(); }
    //any additonal custom logic you may need later...
});
```

A general introduction to JSON-js is provided at the [JSON in JavaScript page](http://www.json.org/js.html), along with some brief intro info about JSON, and the page also includes some usage scenarios.

Answer (score 2):

You can consider leveraging popular library like moment.js http://momentjs.com/

Then you can store date as YYYY-MM-DD in json and let moment handle the parsing:

```
var dateString = '2012-11-01';
var someday = moment(dateString);
var formattedDate = someday.format('ddd, DD MMM YYYY'); // 'Thu, 01 Nov 2012'
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easier just to calculate the current system data whenever you read the file? I may be lacking context here but I don't see the point in storing that in the document.

If you really need to do so you can do as follows

```
var jsonObject = {"now":"new Date()"};
var date = eval(jsonObject.now);
```

Comment: This doesn't work when the json data has Hierarchy. I need to be done it on json itself. Is there any other way?

Comment: @RajaGopal You should clarify what you mean by the "Hierarchy problem". Is it the case that multiple "date" entries may occur at various depths in your json object?

Comment: my json data should be like this, [{"data1": "foo", "Date":"", "childs": [ {"data2": "stack", "Date": ""}{}{}..] } ] and so on

Comment: @RajaGopal You can apply the visitor pattern to traverse the object graph and calculate the current Date jsfiddle.net/SdKzG

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store the date, I would prefer to store as a String with a format like yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm:ss or something like that, and parse it in a Date object when I want to read it in the language I need.

```
obj = {
    dates : ['2012/04/30 10:14:23', '2012/05/01 05:34:01']
}
```

I don't understand exactly what you want, with eval methods (it's an ugly practice), you can add a method to puts the actual date in object, and also adds himself at the children and call the method added in the children.

```
obj = {
    data : "foo",
    addDate : function() {
        this.date = newDate();
        if (this.children) {
            for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
                this.children[i].addDate = this.addDate;
                this.children[i].addDate();
            }
        }
    },
    children : [{
        data : "foo2"
    }]
}
```

PS if you want to store it in a file, then you have to use the eval method (not recommended) storing the methods as a string or evry time you load the file do

```
jsonLoaded; // this var has the json that you store in a file;
var addDate = function() {
    this.date = newDate();
    if (this.children) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.children.length; i++) {
            this.children[i].addDate = this.addDate;
            this.children[i].addDate();
        }
    }
    this.addDate = null; // remove the function we have added
    // delete this.addDate; // if is compatible with browser
}
jsonLoaded.addDate = addDate;
jsonLoaded.addDate();
```

you cannot stringify json objects with functions, because of this, in the second method after add the method addDate, we remove that from the json object (also you can do delete this.addDate, but i don't know if it works in IE)

Answer (score 1):

I use Gson in java to create json output, but Gson does not allow me to put javascript functions into the json.  So this is what I do: Use replacement tags for the places you want to put code(like one of the earlier answers).  Then get the text of the json, replace the tags, and then save the text to your json file:

```
    Map<String, String> dynamicDates = new HashMap<>();
    dynamicDates.put("d1", "new Date()");
    dynamicDates.put("d2", "new Date(2015, 0, 1, 9, 30)");
    dynamicDates.put("d3", "new Date(2015, 0, 1, 12, 30)");

    JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject root = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject level_1_A = new JsonObject();
    JsonObject level_1_B = new JsonObject();
    json.add("root", root);
    root.add("level_1_A", level_1_A);
    root.add("level_1_B", level_1_B);

    level_1_A.addProperty("d1", "${d1}");
    level_1_A.addProperty("d2", "${d2}");
    level_1_B.addProperty("d3", "${d3}");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(json, sb);

    String str = sb.toString();
    for (String key : dynamicDates.keySet()) {
        str = str.replace("\"${" + key + "}\"", dynamicDates.get(key));
    }
    String jsonText = str;
    String javascriptText = "var myJson = " + str + ";";

    System.out.println(jsonText);
    System.out.println(javascriptText);
```

So there is nothing left to be done on the consumption side in using this json. And the first output is:

```
    {
      "root": {
        "level_1_A": {
          "d1": new Date(),
          "d2": new Date(2015, 0, 1, 9, 30)
        },
        "level_1_B": {
          "d3": new Date(2015, 0, 1, 12, 30)
        }
      }
    }
```

My use of json is usually saving it as javascript with an assignment, so this has been working for me.

Answer (score 0):

it will be good to collect all the dates you want to transfer into a

```
Collection<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Convert this collection to a json object and then at the receving end,convert it back to date. You can use joda date time API for conversions.

Answer (score 0):

Inspired from Joseph answer, i thought to replace timestamp using regex with my date function that you want to put.

```
function getDateBeforeDays(days) {
    const currentDate = new Date();
    currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - days);
    return currentDate;
}

function replaceTimestampWithMockDate(jsonString, days) {
    try {
        const timeRegex = /\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}(\.\d+)?([+-]\d{2}:\d{2})?/g;

        // Replace all occurrences of the time format with getDateBeforeDays
        const updatedJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonString).replace(timeRegex, () =>
            getDateBeforeDays(days ?? 40),
        );

        return JSON.parse(updatedJsonString ?? {});
    } catch (error) {
        return jsonString; // Return the original string if there's an error
    }
}

const jsonString = '{"timestamp": "2023-07-25T05:01:18.868+00:00", "value": 42}';
const mockDays = 30; // Replace with the number of days for the mock date

const sanitizedData = replaceTimestampWithMockDate(jsonString, mockDays);
```