# How to pass current datetime in JSON request?

Tags: json

Is there a way to pass the current datetime in REST JSON request?

I've being using below code in SOAP XML request, which is working for SOAP only. Looking for something similar for json.

```
<DateTime>${=import java.text.SimpleDateFormat ; new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss").format(new Date())}</DateTime>
```

Thank you,
Kev

Comment: Please take a look at the answer I provided in the link.

Answer (score 0):

JSON is a file format for portability just like XML. Both the file format goes not have any execution logic in them.

You were using Java code to generate the current date time inside your XML tag.

In JSON, you can do the same. Please take a look at this answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/10311116/1489638